# How to define the best replication factor and the number of partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I get the error `partition 0 does not have a leader` when I try to consume messages from a Kafka queue in Spark. In contrast, for some reason I can write to the same topic without any issue from Spark.

I made some tests from console:

> /usr/bin$ kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list
>   "XXX.XX.XX.XXX:9092,XXX.XX.XX.XXX:9092,XXX.XX.XX.XXX:9092" --topic
>   "test-topic" --time -1

```
WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [Set(test-topic)] from broker [BrokerEndPoint(0,XXX.XX.XX.XXX,9092)] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:110)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:80)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:79)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:124)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:59)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:94)
    at kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell$.main(GetOffsetShell.scala:79)
    at kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell.main(GetOffsetShell.scala)
test-topic:2:1096
test-topic:1:1028
Error: partition 0 does not have a leader. Skip getting offsets
```

So, there is no broker for partition 0, right? But how can I configure Spark to read from the topic even if one of the brokers is down?

Or is it related to how the topic was created?

**UPDATE:**

```
/usr/bin/kafka-topics --describe --zookeeper XXX.XX.XX.XXX:2181 --topic ,test-topic
Topic:test-topic    PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 0    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,1   Isr: 3,1
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 2,1
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 2    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,3   Isr: 2,3
```

Comment: Do you know what's the replication factor for the topic?

Try running something like
bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test

Comment: @ossu54: Yes, please see my update. My principal doubt is: if I have 3 brokers, which replication number and how many partitions should I set when creating the topic? As I understand, the number of partitions should be 2, because this way if one of 3 brokers is off, the Kafka Consumer will still work. Is it correct? I am not sure about the replication factor...

Comment: Partition is the unit of parallelism when consuming from a topic so setting it depends entirely on the throughput you want. If you just want a couple of MB/sec or lower throughput just using a single partition is fine.

If you have 3 kafka nodes/brokers and want the maximum fault tolerance you should set the replication factor to 3. However, from your output I can see that partition 0 has leader 3 and replica 1 meaning in the case that node 3 goes down everything should still work since data is replicated on 1 and a new leader should be assigned.
Which version of Kafka are you running?

Comment: @ossu54: In my case it works only if I create a topic with 2 partitions. But then the thoughtput of the system falls terribly. I think that I have the version of Confluent on the cluster. Do I understand correctly that if I have 3 brokers, then I should create topics with replication factor 1 and number of partitions equal to 2 (otherwise it falls)? Or I should increate the number of brokers to increate the throughtput and to be able to use more partitions and a higher replication factor?